# Using a variable in value name

Tags: scala

How to call two val: foo1 and foo2 randomly.

I managed to generate the name as a string but how can I convert it into a value name to print the value rather than the name.

```
val r = scala.util.Random

val foo0 = 10
val foo1 = 5

println("foo"+r.nextInt(2))
```

gives foo0 or foo1 when I would like 10 or 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *technically* do this with reflection, but you *shouldn't*.

```
class Foo {
  val foo0 = 10
  val foo1 = 5
}

val r = new scala.util.Random

scala> val foo = new Foo
foo: Foo = Foo@f5009c7

scala> foo.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("foo" + r.nextInt(2)).invoke(foo).asInstanceOf[Int]
res19: Int = 10
```

Again, we *shouldn't* do this. It will turn your code into a sprawling mess of a minefield.

If you ever find yourself naming things with indices like `foo0`, `foo1`, `foo2`, etc, that means they probably belong in a collection of some type.

```
val foos = List(10, 5)
```

Then you can access them by index using `apply`:

```
foos.apply(r.nextInt(2))

scala> foos(r.nextInt(2))
res20: Int = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't work in a statically typed language. Pretty sure it's bad practice in any dynamic language too.

Try:

```
List(foo0, foo1)(r.nextInt(2))
```